# Angular Unit Testing : Expect undefined to equal true

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am new in programming and this is the first time im asked to do unit testing in Angular and im a lil bit confused...
I want to test this method in my component.ts:

```
isInputHidden = true;

showInput(){this.isInputHidden = false;}
```

spec.ts :

```
it('should show the input', () => {
component.isInputHidden == false;
let showInput = component.showInput();
expect(showInput).toBe(true);
```

})

When i run this test i get these errors : In jasmine ==> Expect undefined to equal true.
In Terminal ==>  Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected'.
Someone can help me to figure out what should i change?

Comment: you have to return sthg in showInput() (e.g. this.isInputHidden) to initialize showInput

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fix your test :

- initialize your variable with `=` and not `==`
- call directly the function (you can't intiialize the showInput variable with it anyway as the function doesn't return anything)
- the expected variable to test is InputHidden directly as you changed its value with the `showInput()` function

```
it('should show the input', () => {
component.isInputHidden = false; // removed a "="
component.showInput(); // your function will change isInputHidden directly
expect(component.isInputHidden).toBe(true); // test isInputHidden
```

Comment: It worked...  i just had to change toEqual(true) by toEqual(false) because in this case we are talking about the isInputHidden parameter... Thank you :)

Comment: true i inverted the values sorry

Comment: no pb... but when i try to test the other case it doesn't work(isInputHidden = false; expect()tobe(true) ==>Expected false to be true.... i think i need to set the variable isn't it?

Comment: as your property is false and `showInput()` set it to false too, there is no way you can expect it to be true

Comment: You would need a hideInput(){this.isInputHidden = true} to be able to set your property to true after all